# Sharepoint 2007 page layout - view current aspx

Tags: 2007, page-layout, tags

currently using SharePoint 2007 to manage our website content and we use page layouts etc for article pages. We have a live and production environment. I'm trying to find a way to download a copy of the page layout itself so I can see the current asp code.

I'm trying to establish the version of the page which is being used as it seems to be different. Hard to explain as I'm new to this and inexperienced.

Basically Looking at the code in visual studio shows the tag should be

```
<BritishControls:absailingTeamPageControl>
```

But when I look at the page in web browser it throws an exception and says the control is actually :

```
<BritainControls:absailingTeamPageControl>
```

which is an older bversion before we refactored some old code.

Any suggestions or pointer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to achieve this - if you goto the master page gallery (normally /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx) you can look at all the master pages. From there select the one you want and use the drop down - send to> download a copy. You can then see a copy of the aspx page being used.